# How to play html video when iOS low power mode is active?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a html video placed in background with z-index:0
When apple device has low power mode active, it doesn't autoplay video and shows play button, that user can't click because in background.

Is it possible to fix this?

```
<video id="bg-video" preload="preload" playsinline loop muted autoplay>
    <source src="myvideo.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

Comment: Hi, i don't know for ios but in android it's not possible.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50400902/detect-if-ios11-device-is-in-low-power-mode-to-prevent-bad-ux-on-normally-correc?rq=1 suggests also adding the `inline` property - But I feel lots of these workarounds may eventually be patched.

Comment: [Rocky](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15598105) posted an [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67033687) saying "Autoplay video on mobile devices on low power mode: [https://shaktisinghcheema.com/how-to-autoplay-video-on-mobile-devices-on-low-power-mode/](https://shaktisinghcheema.com/how-to-autoplay-video-on-mobile-devices-on-low-power-mode/)"

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to fix this?

Playing a video, especially in the background of a web page, is a relatively power-hungry operation. Low-power mode is functioning correctly by preventing this video from playing.

While there may be some methods which allow this video to autoplay *right now*, these are bugs and are likely to be patched in the future.