# Video autoplay (HTML/CSS) not always working on phone, but sometimes it is

Tags: html, css, video, autoplay

I'm trying to create a simple website and want to just have some videos autoplay.
Now I'm aware there are some changes that make this a little bit harder than it used to be.

Right now I'm dealing with the problem that sometimes it works, sometimes it doesn't. A refresh of the page can make the difference. I've got no clue why that could be, so hopefully you guys can help me.

Desktop works fine.
Mobile it works *sometimes* (page refresh helps often) - I'd like this to be *always*.

The two URLs:

- https://jetweevers.nl/stevieisjarig/2-ja.html
- https://jetweevers.nl/stevieisjarig/bye.html

The code used for the video:

```
<video class="bg-video" src="video/bye.mp4"
   autoplay="autoplay" loop="true" muted defaultmuted playsinline poster="images/bg-2.jpg"> </video>
```

Hope you guys can point me in the right direction!

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Auto-play is restricted for many devices in low-power mode. It's possible this is what you're running into, although a page refresh shouldn't make a difference.

There are many posts about this on SO, but [here's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50400902/detect-if-ios11-device-is-in-low-power-mode-to-prevent-bad-ux-on-normally-correc?noredirect=1&lq=1) one with some solutions that worked for people.